# Least square estimate expected value and variance of linear model

Tags: multiple-regression, variance, linear-model, expected-value, unbiased-estimator

I am practice some exercises. Here it goes.
"Assume we fit the simple model \begin{equation}
\hskip 5cmy=X_1\beta_1+\epsilon   \hskip 5cm (1)
\end{equation}
however the true model is \begin{equation}
\hskip 5cmy=X_1\beta_1+X_2\beta_2+\epsilon    \hskip 5cm          (2) 
\end{equation}
assume for both models above that the model errors $\epsilon$ satisfy $E(\epsilon)=0$ and $Var(\epsilon)=\sigma^2I$

a) What are expected value and variance of the least-squares estimate of the simple model, i.e. (1)?

b) In which situation is $\hat{\beta}_1$ unbiased?

My answer for a: I compute $E(\hat{\beta}_1)$ and obtained $\beta_1$, but I cannot se how I should do it for variance. Anyway to show it? I know a formula $Var(X)=E(X^2)-(E(X))^2$. Can it be useful?

My answer to b: We will have a unbiased $\hat{\beta}_1$ for (2). I found a note in the lecture notes that says that $\hat{\beta}_1$ is biased for (1). I hope someone can help me.

Comment: It's easy to see that $\hat\beta_1$ is biased, unless $X_1$ and $X_2$ are uncorrelated

Comment: So it is biased for both cases? I.e. for (1) and (2)?

Comment: Consider adding the [tag:self-study] tag.

Comment: If you have both terms in the model then it's unbiased again, since it corresponds to the true relationship between variables